# why name class of tag <table> be changed when using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm new to BeatifulSoup. I'm trying to get table element of [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_largest_banks?utm_medium=Exinfluencer&utm_source=Exinfluencer&utm_content=000026UJ&utm_term=10006555&utm_id=NA-SkillsNetwork-Channel-SkillsNetworkCoursesIBMDeveloperSkillsNetworkPY0221ENSkillsNetwork23455645-2021-01-01). This table tag has class = `wikitable sortable mw-collapsible jquery-tablesorter mw-made-collapsible` but in BeautifulSoup the class just is `wikitable sortable mw-collapsible`. Please help me know why.

[image: name class on web]
[image: name class on BeautifulSoup]

Answer (score 0):

#### What happens?

Results differ cause `requests` do not work like a browser - It could not handle dynamic served content and will not interpret / manipulate it like a browser does.

**Note** *Websites change from time to time, but changes to structure are rarer than to styles. Therefore it is always a good strategy to use elements or ids instead of classes for the selection.*